# processDebugManifest error - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I am new to `Android Studio` and when gradle building I get this error :

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
```

and here's my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

and in my `Androidmanifest.xml`, I have

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Could someone help ?

Comment: Please post the output from your Gradle console when you do a build.

Comment: Just a tip. Gradle overrides your Manifest setting like minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to experience the same problem. For my part, it had something to do with building and adding new entries to the dependencies (maybe a cache issue ?). So try to delete each line of the dependencies, and add them progressively, so that you isolate which one is the cause of your problem and, if it is something like a cache issue, it will solve your problem. Hope this help !

Comment: Great it worked ! I deleted all the dependencies, and then added them one by one and it did the trick !!! How can you explain that more precisely ?